# Unable to properly display images with Swing

Tags: java, user-interface

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class PhotoAlbum implements ActionListener {

JFrame frame;
JPanel contentPane;
JButton next;
JLabel pictures;

JLabel sticker;


public PhotoAlbum(){
/* Create and set up the frame */
    frame = new JFrame("Photo Album");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    /* Create a content pane with a BoxLayout and empty borders */
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 100, 100, 100));
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.white);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    /* Create a label that shows the start of the game */
    pictures = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("icecream.gif"));
    pictures.setAlignmentX(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    pictures.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    contentPane.add(pictures);


    /* Create a next button */
    next = new JButton("Next");
    next.setActionCommand("Next");
    next.setAlignmentX(JButton.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    next.addActionListener(this);
    contentPane.add(next);


    /* Add content pane to frame */
    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

    /* Size and then disnext the frame. */
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


/**
 * Handle the button click
 * pre: none
 * post: The appropriate image and message are disnexted.
 */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

     if (event.getSource() == "Next"){
 for ( int count = 0; count < 6; count ++){
    switch (count) {
        case 1: pictures.setIcon(new ImageIcon("icecream.gif")); 
                 break;
        case 2:  pictures.setIcon(new ImageIcon("coffee.gif"));
                 break;
        case 3: pictures.setIcon(new ImageIcon("giraffe.gif"));
                 break;
        case 4:  pictures.setIcon(new ImageIcon("jeep.gif"));
                 break;
        case 5:  pictures.setIcon(new ImageIcon("sunset.gif"));
                 break;
        default: 
    }
    }
 }
}








/**
 * Create and show the GUI.
 */
private static void runGUI() {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    PhotoAlbum Game = new PhotoAlbum();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Methods that create and show a GUI should be
       run from an event-dispatching thread */
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            runGUI();
        }
    });
   }
}
```

This code doesn't show any images. How can I fix it? I tried to rewrite it or use a different statement, but it still doesn't show the picture. Only the botton

Comment: Do the gif files exist? Are they in the correct directory? Have you verified that, for instance,  `new ImageIcon("icecream.gif");` actually returns a non-null value?

Comment: If the `gif`does not exist, it does not return a `null`value.

Comment: The filenames you’ve given to the ImageIcon constructor are relative filenames, so they are not reliable.  You could change each one to an absolute path, but the most reliable approach is to put them in a resource directory and load them using, for example, `new ImageIcon(PhotoAlbum.class.getResource("icecream.gif"))`, which will work regardless of where your project resides.

Comment: Thank you! I put images to the wrong folder and after I changed it worked

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Icons that I knew where there, for example: `UIManager.getIcon("FileView.fileIcon");` This is included in Java libraries, so, we know it exists and we can use it.

If you use it like this: `pictures = new JLabel(UIManager.getIcon("FileView.fileIcon"));`

This is the output:

[image: Fixed]

If you run it with a missing Icon (like your `new ImageIcon("icecream.gif")`), this is the output:

[image: Wrong]

There are no icons, when it can't find them, so you are not accessing the right icon files.

Comment: You were right, I was missing my images, I had them saved in the wrong folder. Thank you

Comment: @Nika If your issue is solved, please, mark it as *Answered* or post the answer yourself to avoid more unnecesary comments. Glad it worked.